# Saving XGBoost to SQL And Loading On Another Machine

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

I have a unique situation where I want to save my XGBoost model to SQL and load it into another machine where it can do predictions.

The problem is I was using Pickle and it has problems loading cross machine. I heard that it can become non-supported at different versions too.

Is there a better alternative that satisfies these requirements?

1. Save model to SQL (preferably binary, but text can work too)
2. Load model on another machine and run predictions.

Comment: I think your only alternative is to Pickle a trained model.,

Comment: It doesn't seem to work cross machine, however. I will explore some alternative options in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

We had a use case where the model *had* to run on the SQL server. We used [xgb2sql](https://github.com/Chryzanthemum/xgb2sql) to convert an xgboost model to SQL that runs reliably on SQL Server. The output is SQL code, i.e. text.